# Find the most common value in array

Tags: javascript, math

I have a multi dimensional array that looks like this:

```
[
   [ 30,  40   ]
   [ 40,  40   ]
   [ 100, 100  ]
   [ 100, 100  ]
   [ 100, 100  ]
   [ 200, 100  ]
   [ 200, 200  ]

]
```

How can I get the value pair that is the most common from it - `[100, 100]` ?

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried? Do you expect us to do all the work?

Comment: no.. just some ideas. I was thinking to join the array values in a string and put that as key in another array. then increase the counter on that array every time I find a duplicate key. but it sounds to complicated, there must be some easier way

Comment: Count each occurrence.

Comment: One of the problems you'll have is that there are no duplicate elements in that array. `[100, 100] === [100, 100]` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fun, I would loop through the pairs and hash them with `item.join("-")`, rather then trying to check each item in the pairs manually. This will also work with pairs of an arbitrarty length. Then just save the has in an object as a key, with the value being the occurrence rate. then you can just grap the max and split the hash back `item.split("-")` to get your pair

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9cex/

**UPDATE**

here is a slightly more optimized version with one loop. It won't handle the case where there are two different pairs of the same frequency, but either will the last one. It will just return the first answer

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9cex/8/

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to do :s i thought there's an easier way to do this, like some built in function or something bc this looks too expensive :(

Comment: I added a less expensive version with one loop, but yeah there isn't a built in way. However I don't think either of these are very performance heavy unless the array is very large

Answer (score 1):

This creates an array of pairs and the respective number of occurrences. Then it finds the pair with the most occurrences. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dujf8/1/).

```
var data = [
   [ 30,  40   ],
   [ 40,  40   ],
   [ 100, 100  ],
   [ 100, 100  ],
   [ 100, 100  ],
   [ 200, 100  ],
   [ 200, 200  ]
];

var countData = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // see if the pair exists, if not increment count

    var exists = false

    for (var j = 0; j < countData.length; j++) {
        if (countData[j].pair[0] == data[i][0] && countData[j].pair[1] == data[i][1]) {
            countData[j].count++;
            exists = true;
        }
    }

    if (!exists) {
        var tmp = new Object();
        tmp.pair = data[i];
        tmp.count = 1;
        countData.push(tmp);
    }
}

var mostFrequentPair = { pair: null, count: 0 };

for (var i = 0; i < countData.length; i++) {
    if (countData[i].count > mostFrequentPair.count) mostFrequentPair = countData[i];
}

console.log('The most frequent pair is [' + mostFrequentPair.pair + '] which occurs ' + mostFrequentPair.count + ' times.');
```

You could add another loop, if you wanted, to find any pairs that were tied for highest number of occurrences.